# How to create a method that formats output of an array with a loop

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a class that calls methods on an array of unknown size and unknown values. I have the entire thing made except the method that formats the output. The class is about locker rentals. If the first locker has been rented for two days, then this would be true:

```
    daysLeftRental[0] == 2;
```

If the locker is available to rent, then this would be true:

```
    daysLeftRental[0] == -1;
```

In other words, any lockers that are available hold a value of -1, since there is no way someone could rent a locker for -1 days. I need to format my output in the following manner:

```
    Locker 0: 3
    Locker 1: Available
    Locker 2: 30
```

And so on and so forth. I have no idea how I would format my code so that when

```
    i = position of locker;
    daysLeftRental[i] == -1;
```

my output says "Available" and when

```
    daysLeftRental[i] >= 0
```

my output says whatever value is stored in daysLeftRental[i]. For reference, this is what my code would look like if I could just return -1 instead of the string "available"

```
    public String toString() {
        String formatOutput = " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < daysLeftRental.length; i++) {
             formatOutput = formatOutput + "\nLocker" 
             + i + ": " + daysLeftRental[i];
        }
        return formatOutput;
    }
```

which would yield:

```
    Locker 0: 3
    Locker 1: -1
    Locker 2: 30
```

Comment: yes sorry it's java I will specify this in the post

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that would be what I'd have to use, but I'm unsure how to go about it. How do I write an if statement that returns a string value in a particular position in some cases and an int in other positions at other times?

Comment: Aruna's answer below shows that, but if you are not familiar with this type of if-statement (inline) you can use normal `if` where you place same line of code in both if and else block but one you leave it as is (>=0) and the other (<0) you write ("Available"). there are many other ways like using a string variable and fill it in if and else blocks , then concatenate it to the main string.

Comment: i have posted an answer for the 3 options.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the one you are trying?

```
public String toString() {
        String formatOutput = " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < daysLeftRental.length; i++) {
             formatOutput = formatOutput + "\nLocker " 
             + i + ": " + (daysLeftRental[i] == -1 ? "Available" : daysLeftRental[i].toString());
        }
        return formatOutput;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
public String toString() {
    String formatOutput = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < daysLeftRental.length; i++) {
         if(daysLeftRental[i] >= 0){
             formatOutput = formatOutput + "\nLocker" 
             + i + ": " + daysLeftRental[i];
         }else{
             formatOutput = formatOutput + "\nLocker" 
             + i + ": Available";        
         }
    }
    return formatOutput;
}
```

or, you can prepare the line before the if-statement, then just append last segmant:

```
public String toString() {
    String formatOutput = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < daysLeftRental.length; i++) {
         formatOutput = formatOutput + "\nLocker" + i + ": ";
         if(daysLeftRental[i] >= 0){
              formatOutput += Integer.toString(daysLeftRental[i]);
         }else{
             formatOutput += "Available";        
         }
    }
    return formatOutput;
}
```

if you don't like to write same line in both if and else, you can use a variable to hold the number or the word "Available"

```
public String toString() {
    String formatOutput = " ";
    String status = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < daysLeftRental.length; i++) {
         if(daysLeftRental[i] >= 0){
             status = Integer.toString(daysLeftRental[i]);
         }else{
             status = "Available";
         }

         //concatenate it:
         formatOutput = formatOutput + "\nLocker" + i + status;
    }
    return formatOutput;
}
```

and you can use inline-if as in Aruna's answer above (if you understand it)
if not, **i would recommend (option-2)**, no much code repeated (option-1), no much variables declared (option-3).

**EDIT:
- -- -- -- --**

i don't want to exaggerate, but you can always use a method, if you know how to use them
create a method that will return either the number or "Available"., the IF-statement goes to the method, and that's it

```
public String getStatus(int x){

    if(x>=0){
        return Integer.toString(x);
    }else{
        return "Available";
    }
}
```

in the for loop, don't use IF-statement at all. just concatenate the result of `getStatus()` call to the line

```
formatOutput = formatOutput + "\nLocker" + i + ": " + getStatus(daysLeftRental[i]);
```